# why does my table th ignore the specified width?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem when setting the width of my th table, when I set it less than 15px it stops working and reaches a limit.

The current width I have doesn't meet my requirements because I need it smaller, but I just can't make it smaller anymore.

I share the small fragment that causes me problems.

I already tried to configure everything, but nothing works for me.

```html
<div class="col-md-12" style="overflow-x: auto;">               
  <div class="table-responsive" style="display: table !important;">
    <table class="bordered table-bordered" style="border:none; table-layout: fixed !important;" id="tabla_1">
      <tr align="center">
        <th style="width: 3px !important; height: 30px; background: #00A7E1; border-color: #00A7E1;"></th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[this is my table but i need to adjust that th as small as possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SvxR.png)

Answer (score 0):

`<th>` width = 3px (your setting) + `<th>` border 2px (left 1px, right 1px) = 5px

You can use `box-sizing: border-box;`

Let the total width be your setting.

Or `<th>` width = 1px instead.

Comment: Don't forget default padding, and should use `border-box` universally.

Comment: Oh...

I found that I wrote `content-box` lol.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the trouble, but it still doesn't fit the width I want it to. I need to adjust it as small as possible, I don't know if my concept is wrong and that can't be done in a table.

Comment: Add an example of th that causes me problems, it is the decoration of the left side

Comment: Can you show the info in developer tool? @VictorLeonardoRoblesOrtega